# How to edit my current mySQL query to achieve the preferred output?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table below, and I want to select all the users that

- have a row with type_id equals to 3 and type = form
- and all the rows with type_id equals to 5 and type = action.

I know I am wrong, but how shall I edit my query?

The table

```
user --- type--- type_id
abc ---- form --- 3
abc ---- action--- 5
abc ---- action--- 3
abc ---- form --- 6
```

Current query

```
Select user 
  from table 
 where type = 'form' type = 'action' 
   and type_id IN(3, 5)
 Group
    By user
Having count(1) = 2;
```

Comment: `where (type = 'form' OR type = 'action') AND type_id IN(3, 5)` or to be consistent `where type IN('form', 'action') AND type_id IN(3, 5)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver i understand what you did there, however I updated my question. The reason is because the type_id of an action may be the same of the type_id of a form

Comment: As you can tell by the two different answers, your question, and especially the desired outcome is unclear. Please make sure you describe the conditions unambiguously and provide example output as well.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pair the conditions for `type` AND `type_id` and use OR:

```
SELECT user FROM table 
    WHERE (type = 'form'   AND type_id = 3)
    OR    (type = 'action' AND type_id = 5)
    GROUP BY user HAVING count(1) = 2;
```

I don't have a gold [mysql] or [sql] badge for a reason (I have no idea what `HAVING count(1) = 2` is).  Off to check it out.

Comment: I want the (type = 'form'   AND type_id = 3) AND (type = 'action' AND type_id = 5)

Comment: That's impossible.  You want x AND y but need to select using OR in this case because `type` can't be form AND action at the same time.

Comment: Try it both ways and you'll see.

Comment: Looks correct to me. `count(1)` is the same as `count(*)`. The condition could also be `(type, type_id) IN (('form', 3), ('action', 5))` - but can probably not be optimized by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give all usernames for the conditions you mentioned above.

```
SELECT t1.user FROM table_name t1 inner join table_name t2 
WHERE (t1.type = 'form' AND t1.type_id = 3) and
(t2.type = 'action' AND t2.type_id = 5)
GROUP BY t1.user;
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/235b08/6)